# display both progressbar and Pagination custom with swiper.js

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I can display either the progressbar or the pagination number with swiper.js. both versions work. But I didn't find a solution to display both at the same time. Has anybody an idea? This is my attempt which displays the numbers. If I change the two pagination sections, it dispays the progress bar:

```
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
            keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        type: "progressbar",
      },
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true,
        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
          return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + "</span>";
        },
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
      mousewheel: {
  releaseOnEdges: true,
},
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to display both the progress bar and pagination numbers at the same time in Swiper.js is by using the renderProgressbar function in the pagination configuration. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper('.mySwiper', {
    keyboard: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      type: 'custom',
      renderCustom: function (swiper, current, total) {
        // Render the progress bar
        var progressBarHtml = '<div class="progressbar"><div class="progressbar-fill" style="width:' + (current / total) * 100 + '%"></div></div>';
        
        // Render the pagination numbers
        var paginationHtml = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
          var className = 'swiper-pagination-bullet';
          if (i === current - 1) {
            className += ' swiper-pagination-bullet-active';
          }
          paginationHtml += '<span class="' + className + '">' + (i + 1) + '</span>';
        }

        // Combine the progress bar and pagination numbers
        return progressBarHtml + paginationHtml;
      }
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    mousewheel: {
      releaseOnEdges: true,
    },
  });
</script>
```

In this modified code, we're using the type: 'custom' and renderCustom options in the pagination configuration to define a custom pagination renderer. Inside the renderCustom function, we first render the progress bar HTML using a  with a filled inner  that represents the progress percentage. Then we loop through the total number of slides and render the pagination numbers using a  element with a swiper-pagination-bullet class. We also add an active class to the current slide's pagination number. Finally, we concatenate the progress bar and pagination HTML and return it as the custom pagination renderer output.

You can modify the CSS styles of the progress bar and pagination numbers by modifying the .progressbar, .progressbar-fill, and .swiper-pagination-bullet CSS classes in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you very much. But this code only displays the bullets. I have the css-styles for swiper-pagination-progressbar - no result. I even tried with an extra html-div with swiper-pagination-progressbar - also no result. did i get you wrong?